# Getting 'Visual Studio 2022 not responding' error when opening cshtml/razor pages - how to solve?

Tags: asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2022 not responding problem when opening cshtml/razor pages

I am facing problem Studio 2022 as not responding after opens cshtml/razor dynamics not a statics pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after closing CodeLens my problem was solved.
CodeLens is a capability that shows the number of references for each class at the top of any class.
[image]

In Visual Studio find it in menu Options → Text Editor → All languages → CodeLens.

Comment: Please suggest for VS 2022 not for vs code i have problem continuously for same